# How does one evaluate a $\max_x \min_y f(x,y)$?

Tags: functions, optimization

I was reading the expression:

$$ \max_x \min_y f(x,y)$$

and wasn't sure how to evaluate such an expression (i.e. if read it "right to left" or "left to right"). In other words, what order is that evaluated? The issue that I have is that it seems to evaluate either we need to know in advance the value of x and y.

This is what I've thought so far:

Assume we choose $y$ first. To choose y, we (supposedly) choose it such that $f(x,y)$ is minimized. However, how does $y$ choose a minimizing $y$ value if $x$ has not be chosen? Similarly, how can $x$ choose a minimizing value if $y$ has not been chose? How does one actually evaluate such a thing>

I've also think I've heard contradicting things that are confusing me.

I've heard that I should evaluate it right to left. I take that to mean to choose y first and then to choose x. Which as I explained above seems confusing. However, I heard of another answer that actually makes more sense to me (seems correct), but seems to contradict the "right to left" order of evaluation (which I heard from more than one person so I feel its ought to be checked). So this is what makes sense to me, think of $\min_y$ as follows:

$$ F(x) = \min_y f(x,y) $$

so we get:

$$ \max_x \min_y f(x,y) = \max_x F(x) $$

which actually makes more sense to me because (say the set is finite) we would loop through the values of x and plug it to F(x) and then just choose whatever comes out largest. So the min is computed for each value of x. So we choose a bunch of x first and see what value of $y$ our "adversary" chooses and then just choose the value of $x$ that makes the adversary's value be largest. But this logic seems to be compute from "left to right".

Is this the correct way to think about it? Is there an easier more intuitive way to think about it? What does this business of "right to left" or "left to right" mean in this context and how does it map to the procedure that I think is correct?

Comment: The way with $F(x)$ is the correct one.

Comment: @LinAlg but just to understand the vocabulary, what does this "left to right" and "right to left" business mean?

Comment: $ \max_x \min_y f(x,y)$ means $ \max_x (\min_y (f(x,y)))$.

Comment: I think those descriptions are too unclear. But so you will: $\min_y f(x,y)$ is an expression that depends on $x$, and can therefore be denoted as $F(x)$. I do not see a clear contradiction with "right to left".

Comment: @LinAlg I just think that because the term "left to right" or visa versa, is not explicit I just don't know what it means. For me it seems that I go over the values of x first to get the inner thing with y evaluated, so its "left to right". Thats how my brain defines this. Which might be wrong, but I don't understand what the alternative would be.